# r: Change atomic in to recursive

Tags: r, atomic

I used the `rvest` package to download comments from a news portal and saved them using `write.csv2` function. It looks that:

```
> str(mydata)
 chr [1:300, 1:7] "~my" "~cos :" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "Author" "Comment" "Time" "NumberOfVotes" ...
```

My aim is to prepare data for text mining, in fact for a word cloud. So at that moment I'm interested only in the "Comment" column. I tried to extract it from a file by `mydata$Comment` command:

```
data1 <- paste(mydata$Comment, collapse= " ")
```

I got response:

```
Error in mydata$Comment : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
```

What should I do in order to transform it into a recursive form?

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data? For example with `dput(mydata)`

Comment: From what you've provided I can't see a column with the name `Comment` to allow you to use `mydata$Comment`. I think you should treat your data a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is in a matrix. Data.frame (or list) subsetting doesn't work for this. Use matrix subsetting, e.g., `mydata[, "Comment"]`. You should study `help("[")`.

You could also turn your matrix into a data.frame using `as.data.frame(mydata)`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  as.data.frame() command resolved problem